# (Tumblr Theme) Vertical Dropdown Menu With Submenus

Tags: css, menu, tumblr, nav, dropdown

I created a vertical dropdown menu with submenus for my custom Tumblr theme. The menu is below a sidebar on the right side.

I was wondering if someone could look over the code for me. I can't tell If there are errors in the code or not. I'm not a coding expert. I did get this code from a tutorial online and made some adjustments to it. I did ask the person who did the tutorial for help but they did not answer me back. I would be thankful if someone can help me with the code or lead me to some good tutorials online.

**Here is the working code:**

```css
#navsmenu, ul, li, li li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
 
    #navsmenu {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 16px;
    right: 176;
    width: 150px;
    height: 27px;
    }
 
    #navsmenu ul {
    line-height: 25px;
    }
 
    #navsmenu li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #79cde2;
    }
 
    #navsmenu li li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #79cde2;
    left: 148px;
    top: -27px;
    }
 
    #navsmenu ul li a {
    width: 148px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
 
    #navsmenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 27px;
    }
 
    #navsmenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    }
 
    #navsmenu li:hover {
    background-color: #f8a542;
    }
 
    #navsmenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f8a542;
    }
 
    #navsmenu a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navsmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">K-POP REVIEWS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">K HIP-HOP REVIEWS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">SHORT K-POP REVIEWS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">SERIOUS K-POP RANTS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">K-POP DANCE COVERS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">LIFE RANTS</a></li>
    </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">RANDOM K-POP</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">K-POP EDITS & GRAPHICS</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What kind of improvements are you looking for?

Comment: You might do better on here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. From what I can see you are using alot of fixed widths and heights, which is fine if your blog is 'set in stone'. But what happens when you add more items to your menu. You also have some repetition in your code. For example, most of the attributes for `#navsmenu li li` are the same for ` #navsmenu li` so you don't need to repeat them. Might also need to see the blog.

Comment: @iharby Okay, thanks. I would give you a link to my blog but it private. I have not published the blog yet, so in order for you to see my blog, I would have to give you a password.

Comment: @sahil I need improvements to the entire css code. I just wanting someone to look over the code to make sure the code looks right or not. If I needing to fix any errors in the code.